# Регулярные выражения php preg_match

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь достать из переменной `$result_text` ГОСТы, когда в переменной храню короткую строку в которую включён какой нибудь ГОСТ, preg_match_all находит. И я получаю массив из одного элемента. Но когда я пишу строку побольше, как в коде ниже, то вхождений вообще не нахожу. Подскажите, что здесь не так?

```
$result_text = "ГОСТ 2.301-68 ЕСКД. Форматы;о наследия (памятниках истории и 
культуры) народов
ГОСТ 34.201-89. Информационная технология. Комплекс стандартов на 
автоматизированные системы. Виды, комплектность и обозначение документов при 
создании автоматизированных систем;
ГОСТ 34.003-90 Информационная технология. Комплекс стандартов на 
автоматизированные системы. Термины и определения;
ГОСТ 34.601-90 Информационная технология. Комплекс стандартов на 
автоматизированные системы. Автоматизированные системы. Стадии создания;
ГОСТ 34.603-92 Информационная технология. Виды испытаний автоматизированных 
систем;РД 50-34.698-90. Методические указания. Информационная технология. 
Комплекс стандартов на автоматизированные системы. Автоматизированные 
системы. Требования к содержанию документов;
";
$result_text = explode("ГОСТ", $result_text);
for ($i=0;$i<count($result_text);$i++){
  $aaa = 'ГОСТ'.$result_text[$i];
  echo $aaa.'<hr><br>';
  if (preg_match_all("/ГОСТ.d{1,10}.d{1,10}.d{1,10}/i",$aaa,$matches)) {
  var_dump($matches);
  echo '<hr>';
 }
  else echo "NO<hr>";
}
```

Comment: Цифры находит `\d`, а не `d`. Попробуйте `if (preg_match_all('~ГОСТ\s*\d+\.\d+-\d+~iu', $result_text, $res)) {
    print_r($res[0]);
}`. См. [демо](https://3v4l.org/a0Rv4).

Comment: Уважаемый! Огромное вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `preg_match_all` напрямую со следующим регулярным выражением:

```
 '~ГОСТ\s*\d+\.\d+-\d+~iu'
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Yeu34Z/1/).

**Подробности**

- `ГОСТ` - строка  `ГОСТ`
- `\s*` - 0 и более пробельных символов
- `\d+` -  1 и более цифр
- `\.` - символ точки
- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр
- `-` - дефис
- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр.

PHP:

```
if (preg_match_all('~ГОСТ\s*\d+\.\d+-\d+~iu', $result_text, $res)) {
    print_r($res[0]);
}
// => Array ( [0] => ГОСТ 2.301-68 [1] => ГОСТ 34.201-89 [2] => ГОСТ 34.003-90 [3] => ГОСТ 34.601-90  [4] => ГОСТ 34.603-92 )
```